# explanation of a for loop java code

Tags: java, for-loop

Could someone give me a detailed explanation of what's going on here; I'm getting confused by the `?`:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < datasize; i++) {
            String data1value = data1.size() > i ? data1.get(i) : null;
            String data2value = data2.size() > i ? data2.get(i) : null;
            String data3value = data3.size() > i ? data3.get(i) : null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *ternary* operator is being used to prevent getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` here. If the size of the `Collection` is `>` than current index `i`, it assigns that value through `get(i)`, otherwise it assigns `null`.

If you had assigned the values directly as

```
 String data1value = data1.get(i);
```

your code *could* break if the loop runs for more than the number of items in the `Collection`.

Answer (score 1):

The ? : operator in Java  is an expression which returns one of two values.

In Java you might write

```
if (a > b) {
  max = a;
}
else {
  max = b;
}
```

Setting a single variable to one of two states based on a single condition is such a common use of if-else that a shortcut has been devised for it, the conditional operator, ?:. Using the conditional operator you can rewrite the above example in a single line like this:

```
max = (a > b) ? a : b;
```

They are used be the reason presented in the response from Ravi Thapliyal.